# Unable to display data in Data Table after selecting File

Tags: python, installation

Using Win 7 64-bit and Python 2.7.8 32-bit. Orange 2014-10-02 py2.7

Selected iris.tab as the tutorial suggests, but when I click on Data Table and then double-click on the icon, no data appears.

When click on Report get

```
KeyError                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\OWWidget.py", line 178, in reportAndFinish
    self.sendReport()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Orange\OrangeWidgets\Data\OWDataTable.py", line 520, in sendReport
    table = self.id2table[id]
KeyError: None
```

I am stuck. What will it take to get Orange working?

Answer (score 0):

Missed the instruction that I need to drag the line from the File icon to the Data Table icon to connect them. The tutorial should explain that earlier in the sequence.